# Wordpress Table didn't look right

Tags: table

I want to build a table based layout.

In the editor all look right:
[image]

But after saving, the page look like this:

[image]

Can someone help?

UPDATE:

The Theme is **Pagelines framework**

And here the code =

```
<table style="width: 594px;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr align="center" valign="middle">
<td height="112">
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.korallen-schmuck.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Bild02x110.png" alt="" width="83" height="110" /></div></td>
<td style="width: 600px; height: 112px;" rowspan="4"><a href="http://www.korallen-schmuck.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Bild15x440.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-69" title="Bild15x440" src="http://www.korallen-schmuck.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Bild15x440.png" alt="" width="440" height="393" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" valign="middle">
<td height="112">
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.korallen-schmuck.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Bild04x110.png" alt="" width="44" height="110" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" valign="middle">
<td height="112">
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.korallen-schmuck.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Bild14x110.png" alt="" width="87" height="110" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" valign="middle">
<td height="112">
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.korallen-schmuck.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Bild17x110.png" alt="" width="112" height="110" /></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh WYSIWYG, you always fail to fulfill the promise.

Comment: hmm I would have said this is actually a CSS issue not a Wordpress issue. Something in your themes CSS is interrupting the table layout possibly float clearing or image margins

Comment: Without seeing the code answers are impossible. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The displacement could be result of the theme you are using. You will have to check what is the width of your content area and compare it to the table overall width (main image + side images + padding inside the cells + padding between the cells + borders, if you are using any). You should also consider any padding of the content area in the theme.

The easies way to avoid going through all of the above is to start testing different sizes of your main image.